# Any way to conditionally skip middleware with next() in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

So for example-

```
//Functions

var validationCheck = function(req, res, next){
  if(req.session.userId && req.session.token)
      next('validationCatch') //Is this possible to skip middleware if not needed?
  else
      next()
}

var getUserId = function(req, res, next){
  req.session.userId = DB.getUserId
  next()
}

var getToken = function(req, res, next){
  req.session.token = DB.getToken
  next()
}

//a catcher function to direct to next function depending on route
var validationCatch = function(req, res, next){
  next()
}

//Routes

app.get(api + '/feature1', validationCheck, getUserId, getToken, validationCatch, feature1)
app.get(api + '/feature2', validationCheck, getUserId, getToken, validationCatch, feature2)
```

My goal is to skip unnecessary middleware if information is already cached from previous routes. So in above example, feature2 doesnt have to enter `getUserId` and `getToken` if feature1 has already been called, thus making response faster.

If not possible, please state a more efficient architecture to handle repetitive validation processes. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Instead of register the callbacks directly, just call them in `validationCheck` if needed.
Here is a simple example with `getUserId`:

```
var validationCheck = function(req, res, next){
  if(req.session.userId)
      next()
  else {
    getUserId(req, res, function(err){
      next(err)
    })
  }      
}
```